# Why does segmentation fault (core dumped) error apply to my C program?

Tags: c

I keep getting this error and I am not sure how it applies to my program. This is my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int nextword(char *str);



void main(void)
{
  char *str = "Hello! Today is a beautiful day!!\t\n";
  int i = nextword(str);
  while(i != -1)
    {
      printf("%s\n",&(str[i]));
      i = nextword(NULL);
    }
}

int nextword(char *str)
{
  // create two static variables - these stay around across calls
  static char *s;
  static int nextindex;
  int thisindex;
  // reset the static variables
  if (str != NULL)
    {
      s = str;
      thisindex = 0;
      // TODO:  advance this index past any leading spaces
      while (s[thisindex]=='\n' || s[thisindex]=='\t' || s[thisindex]==' '                )
    thisindex++;  

    }
  else
    {
      // set the return value to be the nextindex
      thisindex = nextindex;
    }
  // if we aren't done with the string...
  if (thisindex != -1)
    {
      nextindex = thisindex;
      // TODO: two things
      // 1: place a '\0' after the current word
      // 2: advance nextindex to the beginning
      // of the next word
      while (s[nextindex] != ' ' || s[nextindex] != '\n' || s[nextindex] != '\t')
    {
      if ( s[nextindex] == '\0')
        return -1;
      else
        {
          nextindex++;
          if (s[nextindex]==' '||s[nextindex]=='\n'||s[nextindex]=='\t')
        str[nextindex]='\0';
        }
    }

    }
  return thisindex;
}
```

My program is supposed to have an output to the console of

```
Hello!
Today
is 
a
beautiful 
day!!
```

Comment: You won't know until you run it in a debugger.

Comment: I failed to mention I am a beginning programmer and have not learned about running a debugger.

Comment: You are modifying a string literal, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: ...or even add some `printfs` so you can see how far it is getting.

Comment: Then now is  perfect time to learn! :) It will help you find the location of the crash, as well as let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: @Michael_19 - Probabley best to learn about a debugger.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to change a [String literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). This results in undefined behavior, such as a segfault.

```
str[nextindex]='\0'
```

and in Here, `str` is the parameter of `nextWord()`, which is:

```
char *str = "Hello! Today is a beautiful day!!\t\n";
int i = nextword(str);
```

Since `"Hello! Today is a beautiful day!!\t\n"` is a string literal - changing it is udnefined behavior, and in your case (luckily) it caused a seg-fault.

Comment: How should I add the '\0' to the end of the word so that only that word or simplified string is printed?

Comment: You will have to copy the string, and modify the copy of it. You can use the [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) function to copy a string. Note you can freely modify a string which is not a string literal - no harm there.

Answer (score 4):

You should compile with all warnings and debugging info enabled (if using *GCC* e.g. on Linux, that means compiling with `gcc -Wall -g`).

Then you should learn how to use the debugger (i.e. `gdb` on Linux) and possibly a leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) may happen if you dereference some "bad" pointer, e.g. a NULL one or an uninitialized one. It also may happen if you write into a read-only segment (you are probably overwriting a string literal which is put into a read-only -so called `.text` or `.rodata`- segment)

Taking account of every warning of the compiler (and enabling them) and using a debugger are essential skills of any C programmer.

Comment: Though I agree with the general suggestion - Will the compiler generate any warning for **this** issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please give `nextindex` a initial value

Comment: This should really be a comment

Comment: @JasonCoco - Why? - It is the start of the problem.As to the use of `thisIndex`

Comment: That may be a problem if he calls his function with NULL first, but won't cause the problem in the question, thus it should be a comment suggesting correct coding conventions and not an answer to this particular question, IMHO.

Comment: @JasonCoco - You can go through that code without`nextindex` getting an initial value.

Comment: Only if you initially pass NULL to the nextword function, which he does not do. The first time you call it, you pass a value and thisindex gets initialized in the first branch. At this point, the second branch will execute true unless the string is exactly the right size to overflow an int to -1, which it is not in this question, and nextindex will be initialized to the current position. It's very poor and error prone, but not the proximate cause of the segfault.